# Braces in Quantum Circuits with qasm2circ

Tags: braces, circuits

How can I put braces at the edges of a quantum circuit using [`qasm2circ`](http://www.media.mit.edu/quanta/qasm2circ/)?

I want to put a `}` type brace embracing several qubits at the end and/or the beginning of a circuit, but I do not know how to use the command `\frm{\}}` from `xypic` to do so.

Does anybody know? Thank you very much!

My trial is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{xyqcirc.tex}

\def\bA{\q{q_n}}
\def\bB{\q{q_{n-1}}}
\def\bC{\q{q_1}}    
\def\bD{\q{q_0}}    
\def\gAA{\op{H}\w\A{gAA}}    
\def\gBA{\gnqubit{\;\;\;\;U\;\;\;\;}{ddd}\w\A{gBA}}    
\def\gBB{\gspace{\;\;\;\;U\;\;\;\;}\w\A{gBB}}    
\def\gCC{\gspace{\;\;\;\;U\;\;\;\;}\w\A{gCC}}    
\def\gDD{\gspace{\;\;\;\;U\;\;\;\;}\w\A{gDD}}    
\def\H{\w\A{H}}    
\def\S{\w\A{S}}

\xymatrix@R=5pt@C=10pt{
        \bA &\gBA & \n  
\\  \bB &\gBB & \H
\\  \bC &\gCC & \S  
\\  \bD &\gDD & \n   
%
% Vertical lines and other post-xymatrix latex
%
\frm{\}}"H";"S"
} 
\end{document}
```

which gives me no error but the following result:

[image]

Anybody?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). This is basically your functioning, compilable code before the error/problem we are currently discussing. In other words, show us your "best attempt", it helps us a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure such large braces can easily done with `xypic` (see lack of `xypic` answers to [Using xy-pic, how do you label an arrow with a curly brace that spans the length of the arrow, and can be offset arbitrary distances?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87283/106162) for example).  I suspect the easier route would be to make the same diagram with TikZ, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199799/106162) would be a good starting point for doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dai Bowen, but I would like to do it in `xypic` if possible...

Answer (score 3):

Using `qcircuit` (also based on `xy`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
\[
  \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_n}}     & \multigate{3}{U} & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_{n-1}}} & \ghost{U}        & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_1}}     & \ghost{U}        & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_0}}     & \ghost{U}        & \qw
    \inputgroupv{1}{4}{1.3em}{2.4em}{\ket{\psi}} \\
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. My problem is that I have some other quantum circuits on which I would like to draw braces, and I am not sure if I could easily generate those circuits with `qcircuit`, since I have never used it before...

Answer (score 1):

Use standard TeX bracing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\input{xyqcirc.tex}

\newcommand\bA{\q{q_n}}
\newcommand\bB{\q{q_{n-1}}}
\newcommand\bC{\q{q_1}}    
\newcommand\bD{\q{q_0}}    
\newcommand\gAA{\op{H}\w\A{gAA}}    
\newcommand\gBA{\gnqubit{\quad U\quad}{ddd}\w\A{gBA}}    
\newcommand\gBB{\gspace{\quad U\quad}\w\A{gBB}}    
\newcommand\gCC{\gspace{\quad U\quad}\w\A{gCC}}    
\newcommand\gDD{\gspace{\quad U\quad}\w\A{gDD}}    
\newcommand\wH{\w\A{H}}    
\newcommand\wS{\w\A{S}}


$\xymatrix{\q{\psi}}\left\lbrace
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@R=5pt@C=10pt{
  \bA &\gBA & \n  \\
  \bB &\gBB & \wH \\
  \bC &\gCC & \wS \\
  \bD &\gDD & \n
}
\end{gathered}
\right.
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid using `\def` and, in particular, don't redefine `\H` or `\S'; you may regret doing so when your bibliography refers to some Hungarian author.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to put several braces on a single circuit? For example, one embracing the two uppermost qubits and another one for the two lowermost qubits.