# How to add a brace in the output side of my quantum circuit?

Tags: braces, qcircuit

I want to add a brace in the output side of my quantum circuit, I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386765/214374) which gives a solution to add a brace in the input side, I tried to reproduce the same for the output where I used `\ouputgroupv{1}{4}{1.3em}{2.4em}{\ket{\psi}}` instead of `\inputgroupv{1}{4}{1.3em}{2.4em}{\ket{\psi}}`, but it doesn't work.

How can I add this brace using Qcircuit?

Comment: please see if the answer meets your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `\gategroup` command-- since no code has been provided I take the same example as linked in your question and the brace is put on the output side--the `\gategroup{row1}{column6}{row4}{column6}{0.8em}{\}}` are the options for the command

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
\[
  \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_n}}     & \multigate{3}{U} & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_{n-1}}} & \ghost{U}        & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_1}}     & \ghost{U}        & \qw \\
    &&& \lstick{\ket{q_0}}     & \ghost{U}        & \qw \gategroup{1}{6}{4}{6}{.8em}{\}}
    \inputgroupv{1}{4}{1.3em}{2.4em}{\ket{\psi}} \\
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

**edit-- with new code from OP**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
\[
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
     \lstick{\ket{i}} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \qw \\ 
     \lstick{\ket{j}} & \qw&\targ & \qw\gategroup{1}{4}{2}{4}{.8em}{\}}
    }
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't add my circuit; here is mine: `\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
\lstick{\ket{i}} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \qw \\
\lstick{\ket{j}} & \qw&\targ & \qw}`     Could give the right (parameters) code for my circuit to add a brace in the Input and output as you did above, because I tried it but it get shifted :)

Comment: And it is possible to add the ket psi on both sides?

Comment: @Walid -- please see edit above-- in case it has helped please upvote the answer --- further modifications please start a new question

Comment: Thank @js bibra that was helpful. Can I add a $\ket{\psi}$ in front of the output brace?

Comment: I figure out that this is possible by adding in front of  `\gategroup...` this `&&&& \lstick{\ket{\psi^{ij}}}` but this will write it aligned with the second wire, how can I place it in the middle?

Comment: i suggest a new question so that other knowledgeable members can contribute